# What is the correct way to import a custom module under library that is part of a custom role

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, ansible

I created an Ansible custom module that lives embedded in a custom Ansible role

This is the files tree:

```
my-role/
  library/
    my_module.py
  test/
    units/
      test_module.py
```

I want to test my_module so I wanted to import and start testing

I tried several things under the `test_module.py`

1. Tried to do something like this:

```
target = __import__("my_module")
myfunc = target.my_function
```

also, I tested with "library/my_module.py"

and I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/units/test_module.py", line 1, in <module>
    target = __import__("library/my_module.py")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'library/my_module'
```

1. I tried to move my `test_module.py` in the same directory of `my_module.py`

```
my-role/
  library/
    my_module.py
    test_module.py
```

I got the same error but it says `is not a package`

Any idea, documentation, or a guide I can follow?

Thanks

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding the envvar `PYTHONPATH=library python ./test/units/test_features.py` should be the best way to work on this?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add the path of the package to `sys.path`.  I'm not sure if this is the recommended way, but this way has always worked for me.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..')))
```

Then, you should be able to import in your test module.

```
import library.my_module
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it gives me some errors, I fixed my issue by adding the envVar PYTHONPATH=library python ./test/units/test_module.py

Comment: What were the errors? I created the same tree structure you had and didn't have any issues.

Comment: tks, I had `Unable to import 'library.my_module'`